# Issues embedding map with CartoDB

Tags: carto, visualisation

We're having issues embedding a visualization into http://unitedlayer.com/fastest-growing-san-francisco-companies

Previously, the embed code worked just fine. Once we pushed the map to the live site, we lost it entirely.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it a sharing / permissions issue?

Comment: Not as fas as I can tell. The code was good, I've re-visualized the map, spat out new code which works just fine. http://unitedlayer.cartodb.com/viz/a828264a-b6d1-11e4-ab68-0e018d66dc29/embed_map Could the embed code "expire"?

Comment: could it be an HTTPS issue? Is your embed pointing to the normal URL inside a https site? trying changing your visualization URL to https

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you got the link incorrect?

Looking at your public profile, there's a map with the same title as your article that works:

https://unitedlayer.cartodb.com/viz/eb39ed5c-a645-11e4-ac00-0e018d66dc29/embed_map

It has a different URL than is listed in the console when I try loading the page you linked to.

Comment: Initially, the link to the map worked. In any case, I've sent a note to the developer to update the URL. Thanks Andy!